# Why is there an Agora video call issue : "Can't publish stream, haven't joined yet!" while it's in "await"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, agora.io

So here is my code:
VideoCall.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { config, useClient, useMicrophoneAndCameraTracks, channelName} from "./settings.js";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import Video from "./Video.jsx";
import Controls from "./Controls";

export default function VideoCall(props) {
  const { setInCall } = props;
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);
  const client = useClient();
  const { ready, tracks } = useMicrophoneAndCameraTracks();

  useEffect(() => {
    let init = async (name) => {
      client.on("user-published", async (user, mediaType) => {
        await client.subscribe(user, mediaType);
        if (mediaType === "video") {
          setUsers((prevUsers) => {
            return [...prevUsers, user];
          });
        }
        if (mediaType === "audio") {
          user.audioTrack.play();
        }
      });

      client.on("user-unpublished", (user, mediaType) => {
        if (mediaType === "audio") {
          if (user.audioTrack) user.audioTrack.stop();
        }
        if (mediaType === "video") {
          setUsers((prevUsers) => {
            return prevUsers.filter((User) => User.uid !== user.uid);
          });
        }
      });

      client.on("user-left", (user) => {
        setUsers((prevUsers) => {
          return prevUsers.filter((User) => User.uid !== user.uid);
        });
      });

      try {
        await client.join(config.appId, name, config.token, null);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error");
      }

      debugger; 
      
      if (tracks) await client.publish([tracks[0], tracks[1]]);
      setStart(true);
    };

    if (ready && tracks) {
      try {
        init(channelName);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }, [channelName, client, ready, tracks]);

  return (
    <Grid container direction="column" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <Grid item style={{ height: "5%" }}>
        {ready && tracks && (
          <Controls tracks={tracks} setStart={setStart} setInCall={setInCall} />
        )}
      </Grid>
      <Grid item style={{ height: "95%" }}>
        {start && tracks && <Video tracks={tracks} users={users} />}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Video.jsx:

```
import { AgoraVideoPlayer } from "agora-rtc-react";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Video(props) {
  const { users, tracks } = props;
  const [gridSpacing, setGridSpacing] = useState(12);

  useEffect(() => {
    setGridSpacing(Math.max(Math.floor(12 / (users.length + 1)), 4));
  }, [users, tracks]);

  return (
    <Grid container style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <Grid item xs={gridSpacing}>
        <AgoraVideoPlayer
          videoTrack={tracks[1]}
          style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
        />
      </Grid>
      {users.length > 0 &&
        users.map((user) => {
          if (user.videoTrack) {
            return (
              <Grid item xs={gridSpacing}>
                <AgoraVideoPlayer
                  videoTrack={user.videoTrack}
                  key={user.uid}
                  style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                />
              </Grid>
            );
          } else return null;
        })}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Controls.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useClient } from "./settings";
import { Grid, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import ExitToAppIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExitToApp";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faMicrophone, faMicrophoneSlash, faVideoSlash, faVideo } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export default function Controls(props) {
  const {t} = useTranslation();
  const client = useClient();
  const { tracks, setStart, setInCall } = props;
  const [trackState, setTrackState] = useState({ video: true, audio: true });

  const mute = async (type) => {
    if (type === "audio") {
      await tracks[0].setEnabled(!trackState.audio);
      setTrackState((ps) => {
        return { ...ps, audio: !ps.audio };
      });
    } else if (type === "video") {
      await tracks[1].setEnabled(!trackState.video);
      setTrackState((ps) => {
        return { ...ps, video: !ps.video };
      });
    }
  };

  const leaveChannel = async () => {
    await client.leave();
    client.removeAllListeners();
    tracks[0].close();
    tracks[1].close();
    setStart(false);
    setInCall(false);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
      <Grid item>
        <Button variant="contained" color={trackState.audio ? "primary" : "secondary"} onClick={() => mute("audio")} >
          {trackState.audio ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMicrophone} /> : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMicrophoneSlash} />}
        </Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Button variant="contained" color={trackState.video ? "primary" : "secondary"} onClick={() => mute("video")} >
          {trackState.video ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faVideo} /> : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faVideoSlash} />}
        </Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Button variant="contained" color="default" onClick={() => leaveChannel()} >
              {t('agora.leave')}
          <ExitToAppIcon />
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

settings.js:

```
import {createClient, createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks} from 'agora-rtc-react';

export const config = {mode: 'rtc', codec: "vp8", appId: process.env.AGORA_APP_ID, token : process.env.AGORA_TOKEN};
export const useClient = createClient(config);
export const useMicrophoneAndCameraTracks = createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks();
export const channelName = process.env.AGORA_CHANNEL_NAME;
```

AgoraDemo.jsx:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Form, Modal, Button,Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import VideoCall from "./agora/VideoCall";

const AgoraDemo = ({subjects}) => {
  const {t} = useTranslation();
  const [subjectSelected, setSubjectSelected] = useState(null);
  const [inCall, setInCall] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Modal.Dialog size='xl'>
        <Modal.Header style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Modal.Title>
                {t('agora.headline')}
            </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
            <div className="App" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
                {subjectSelected && inCall ? (
                    <VideoCall setInCall={setInCall} />
                ) : (
                    <Button onClick={() => setInCall(true)}>
                        {t('agora.join call')}
                    </Button>
                )}
            </div>
        </Modal.Body>

        <Modal.Footer/>
    </Modal.Dialog>
  )
}

export default AgoraDemo;
```

I don't know much plain javascript so I don't understand why this await does not pass first before proceding to the next line of code and how I should fix it. This is the error:

> ×
> Unhandled Rejection (AgoraRTCException): AgoraRTCError INVALID_OPERATION: Can't publish stream, haven't joined yet!
> ▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
> async init
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/Agora/src/agora/VideoCall.jsx:53
> 50 |
> 51 |      debugger;
> 52 |
> 53 |      if (tracks) await client.publish([tracks[0], tracks[1]]);
> | ^  54 |      setStart(true);
> 55 |    };
> 56 |

Answer (score 0):

The implementation was working. The problem was with the token. It turned out it expires (but didn't get afteh how long exactly) and then you get the given error. For me the solution was to obtain a token for every video call. This way I don't need to renew it manually every time it expires :)